# iOS Swift Add UIImageView as UITabView item

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

is there any way to add `UIImageView` inside `UITabView` as `UITabViewItem`?
I need tab bar like Instagram tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you want to set the image of a `UITabBarItem`?

To do that you would use

```
tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "someImage")
```

Or whatever other way you want to init the `UIImage`.

Edit: You could use a `UIImageView` in place of a `UITabBarItem` in the following way:

```
let firstView = tabBar.subviews.first as! UIImageView
```

Comment: Could you please comment regarding the down vote so I can adjust my answer? For example if I am off topic, or just plain wrong. Thanks

Comment: thanks but : Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarButton' to 'UIImageView'